# Google maps API request definition

Tags: google-maps

In the google maps API usage limits, it is mentioned 2,500 requests per day.
please define request with respect to Street view Google Maps API.

Comment: where did you read about 2.500 in conjunction  with the StreetView-API?

Comment: Not exactly w.r.t to Street view, https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usagelimits

Comment: I also read elsewhere that for Street view it is map loads and its 25,000 map loads in 24 hours for 90 consecutive days . Pls correct me if I m wrong. Also, I would like to understand what google map transactions is considered as request. (For ex: Zooming in/out, navigating across panos, or clicking on map etc)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?csw=1#usage_mapload

Comment: I want a clarification on when we search for a business and we click on the corresponding "See Inside", what API is used? Is it Street View API? With respect to this, I want to know when used for commercial purpose, what is the usage limits? 2500 requests per day or 25,000 map loads per day? I want to estimate for an application which is built around "See inside" technology depending on traffic. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: It's not clear which methods you use to build your application. When you draw a map and request data/show StreetViewPanoramas by using the methods of the Javascript-API the only relevant quota is mapLoads(25k/day), and it will count 1 each time you create a map....subsequent calls will not affect your quota

Answer (score 0):

I think you misread it. The limit is "Free until exceeding 25,000 map loads per day for 90 consecutive days"

Check out full licensing details here: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/